# Terminating SSL at an AWS ELB instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb, pki

I need to terminate SSL at an AWS ELB instance. IT/Ops has provided me with a ZIP file with the following contents:

- `DigiCertCA2.pem`
- `TrustedRoot.pem`
- `wildcard_example_com.crt`
- `wildcard_example_com.csr`
- `wildcard_example_com.key`
- `wildcard_example_com.pem`

(In reality the domain is obviously not `example.com`; but this is a wildcard cert for our own domain.)

According to the [ELB/SSL docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html):

> If you have a certificate ready to upload, select Upload a new SSL Certificate to AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM). Enter the name of the certificate. In Private Key, copy and paste the contents of the private key file (PEM-encoded). In Public Key Certificate, copy and paste the contents of the public key certificate file (PEM-encoded). In Certificate Chain, copy and paste the contents of the certificate chain file (PEM-encoded), unless you are using a self-signed certificate and it's not important that browsers implicitly accept the certificate.

However, I'm not sure which cert is the "Certificate Chain File", or if that is even necessary. I believe these certs are signed by a root/trusted CA (not self-signed).

I have no preference whether I do this in the web console or the AWS CLI tool, **but what steps/actions do I need to take with my specific files in order to get the ELB properly configured with SSL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't do this through the old IAM service method, use the new AWS ACM service to manage the certificate. The ACM service also has a nice web interface for doing this.

The company you got the cert from should be able to tell you which file is the chain file, and yes the chain file is required if you want browsers to properly see your SSL certificate as valid. I did a little searching and found [this blog post](http://www.robertbrewitz.com/2014/09/aws-and-setting-up-a-custom-ssl-certificate/) which discusses using Digicert certificates with AWS. It looks like your files are as follows:

- wildcard_example_com.key = private key file
- wildcard_example_com.crt = public key file
- DigiCertCA2.pem and TrustedRoot.pem combined = certificate chain

Comment: Thanks @Mark B (+1) - so that blog post advocates using the AWS CLI to accomplish this, specifically the `aws iam upload-server-certificate` command. That command takes a `--certificate-chain file://path/to/aws_chain.pem` argument. However, it sounds like you're saying that I have two (2) files in my chain (DigiCertCA2 + TrustedRoot). So do I need to somehow first combine these two files into a single PEM? Or is there a way to specify both of them in this argument? Thanks again!

Comment: 1. It's an old blog post and even has a warning at the top that says it might be outdated, so don't take his advice on using the IAM service via the AWS CLI. That's just the old method that you had to use before the ACM service became available. 2. He is telling you "paste the output from the following commands" into some files, and that is also exactly what you need to paste into the AWS ACM web console. 3. If you look at the certificate chain command, he is actually chaining two commands together to create the certificate chain from those two files.

Comment: The only part of this blog post you need to follow is the three sections with "Private Key", "Public Key Certificate Field" and "Certificate Chain Field" as the titles. From that you will obtain the three PEM encoded files you will need to upload to AWS.